# how to print new line in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>multiplication table</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var i, j;
    var m = 1;

    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            document.write(i * j);
        }
        document.write("\n");
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Output:**

> 12345678910 2468101214161820 36912151821242730 481216202428323640
>   5101520253035404550 6121824303642485460 7142128354249566370
>   8162432404856647280 9182736455463728190 102030405060708090100

it gives output without printing the new line. I want to execute this without using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `<br />` to print text on new line. When you are putting the content in `DOM`. `\n` will just add a space instead of newline.

```
document.write("<br />");
```

Example:

```js
var i, j;
var m = 1;

for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
    document.write(i * j);
  }
  document.write("<br />");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of **document.write("\n");** in your code add document.write("

Code Goes here -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>multiplication table</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var i, j;
    var m = 1;

    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            document.write(i * j);
        }
        document.write("<br/>");
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var i, j;
var m = 1;

for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
    document.write(i * j + "\n\n");
  }
  document.write("<br />");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `document.write("\n");` with `document.write("<br />");`

See the fiddle: "https://jsfiddle.net/godcb7L2/"

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     var i, j;
     var m = 1;
      for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
       for (j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
       document.write(i * j);
       }
      document.write("<br />");
     }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `<br/>`, `<br><br/>`? `<br>` should be supported according to this source, though.

Like: `document.write("<br/>")`

[Supported HTML tags](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)